# Why the error occured python3 with selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-remotedriver

I learning python recent, but I have some error.

environment python3 , chrome , webdriver(chrome)

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
import random
import urllib3
urllib3.disable_warnings(urllib3.exceptions.InsecureRequestWarning)

driver = webdriver.Chrome("./chromedriver.exe") 

mobile_emulation = { "deviceName": 'Nexus 5' }
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()


chrome_options.add_experimental_option("mobileEmulation", mobile_emulation)


driver = webdriver.Remote(command_executor='https:xxx.com',desired_capabilities = chrome_options.to_capabilities())


driver.get("https:/xxx.com")

num = random.randint(11111111 , 99999999)

red = driver.find_element_by_class_name("***")
red.click()

numBox = driver.find_element_by_name("***")
numBox.send_keys(int(num))

reader = driver.find_element_by_id("***")
reader.send_keys("***")

comment = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(" ***")
comment.click()
```

and result error is here

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\python\pad\pad.py", line 16, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Remote(command_executor='https:xxx.com',desired_capabilities = chrome_options.to_capabilities())
  File "C:\Users\***\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 156, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "C:\Users\***\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 254, in start_session
    self.session_id = response['sessionId']
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

I think the error because number of this code includes　Decimal. but I cant find such number .

please give me advise

Comment: Is your web driver up-to-date?

Comment: I installed driver two days ago.so...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error message...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\python\pad\pad.py", line 16, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Remote(command_executor='https:xxx.com',desired_capabilities = chrome_options.to_capabilities())
.
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

...implies that there was a *TypeError* while invoking **`webdriver.Remote()`** method.

As per your code trials as you are using **`webdriver.Remote()`** with the argument **`command_executor`** perhaps you were trying to execute your tests in **Selenium Grid Configuration**.

As per the documentation [documentation](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.html#module-selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver):

- `command_executor` : remote_connection.RemoteConnection object used to execute commands.

  - Example:

    ```
    command_executor='http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub'
    ```
  - The complete implementation:

    ```
    driver = webdriver.Remote(command_executor='http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub', desired_capabilities = chrome_options.to_capabilities())
    ```

**Note**: Here we have considered that the **Selenium Grid Hub** and **Selenium Grid Node** are configured, up and running successfully with default configuration on the localhost.

### Solution (Python 3.6)

Your effective code block will be:

```
from selenium import webdriver

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
chrome_options.add_argument("start-maximized")
chrome_options.add_argument('disable-infobars')
#driver = webdriver.Remote(command_executor='https:xxx.com', desired_capabilities = chrome_options.to_capabilities())
driver = webdriver.Remote(command_executor='http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub', desired_capabilities = chrome_options.to_capabilities())
driver.get('https://www.google.co.in')
print("Page Title is : %s" %driver.title)
driver.quit()
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment . I dont have file in http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub  . Is it OK? I refer this site https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/mobile-emulation  python code.

Comment: ADDITION : I want to browser test in smartphone site.

Comment: @unowen Can you please take out some time to go through my answer once again? The argument `command_executor` is used when you use **Selenium Grid** configuration which involves a **Hub** and a **Node**. If you are not using **Selenium Grid** you shouldn't use the _argument_ `command_executor`.

Comment: to clarify: `command_executor` is for remote webdriver. ...  regardless if you are using a grid *or* a standalone selenium server.